# Recompiling and restarting java without losing state

Tags: java

Let's say I have an application which requires realtime tracking the state of something. Tracking happens via events that I get from an external process. I am in the process of developing it, and I need to quickly fix a class member function that handles an event that is not related to class structure.

For that I would need to recompile and restart, during which my application state would be lost. I could save the state in a file or something, but:

Events are time critical, and I cannot afford to lose even a millisecond, since it is unacceptable to not handle an event. I was wondering if there was any way whatsoever to approach this problem.

Edit:

I'm using classes to keep track of data, but their lifetime cycle is never more than a minute and they're never actually stored anywhere after that, and they are deleted. The data is stored in class instance members and I cannot afford to lose track of any of them.

Note that I am also using these classes in multiple threads.

Comment: You can [reload a class during runtime](https://www.toptal.com/java/java-wizardry-101-a-guide-to-java-class-reloading)

Comment: This question is much too broad. You might want to look into dynamic class reloading (as per the answer below) or a different deployment model that allows you to run multiple version of the application at a time.

Comment: Are you really really really sure you want to generate code at runtime? Why can't you implement some strategy pattern to handle the events? Is the code injected?

Comment: Sorry, it's broad because I did not know where to start searching or even what to google in this case. What kind of strategy pattern could I implement?

Comment: Write a small, simple process to capture the events and write them to a file.  Your larger, more complicated application to process the events can be recompiled in the normal way, and you won't lose any events.  They will be in the file.

Comment: It can be done by JRebel, they also support remoting so I would assume you will be able to do it in a remote container also from developer machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to implement [dynamic class reloading](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html).

Note, though, that reloading a class doesn't magically convert the instances of the original class to instances of the modified class - instead, you'll get a *new* class from which you can create new instances. If you're only using your class to process data but not to store data, you should be fine.

Comment: I'm using classes to keep track of data, but their lifetime cycle is never more than a minute and they're never actually stored anywhere after that, and they are deleted.

Comment: @Nirri: Then it should work well; you can simply keep a reference to the most recently loaded `Class` object and use that to create new instances whenever you need them.